# TCL script to find a script and add new text before searched string with number

Tags: shell, tcl, tk-toolkit

Below is the partial content of my input file:

```
   xyz 
   abc
   MainContent(abc_dt) {
      sc: it;
    }
    MainContent(xyz_cnt) {
      sc : it;
    }
    MainContent(asd_zxc) {
      sc : it;
    }
```

Here, I want to search "MainContent" line and want to add new line before it ... this new line should have "Sb (text which is inside bracket in MainContent_1)"... this should also add opening bracket and closing bracket before next Sb occurance:

Expected output from the script:

```
   xyz 
   abc
   Sb(abc_dt_sb1) {
   MainContent(abc_dt) {
      sc: it;
    }
   }
   Sb(xyz_cnt_sb2) {
    MainContent(xyz_cnt) {
      sc : it;
    }
   } 
   Sb(asd_zxc_sb3) {
      MainContent(asd_zxc) {
      sc : it;
    }
   }
```

Can someone please help to me create a TCL script for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will take your text to be processed on standard input and produce the results on standard output. Redirect it as required.

```
set counter 0
set expectBrace false
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    if {!$expectBrace && [regexp {^\s*MainContent\s*\((\w+)\)} $line -> bits]} {
        puts [format "Sb(%s_sb%d) \{" $bits [incr counter]]
        set expectBrace true
    }
    puts $line
    if {$expectBrace && [regexp {^\s*\}\s*$} $line]} {
        puts "\}"
        set expectBrace false
    }
}
```

Using regular expressions to do the matching of the triggers for state changes in a little state machine (two states, governed by `expectBrace`) is pretty conventional parsing. I've used `format` to do the substitutions into the `Sb(…)` line; these are simple enough that you could use direct substitutions instead if you prefer.

I've not done anything about adding indentation.

Comment: I've assumed that it's wrapping a `MainContent` and not just putting a closing brace immediately before the next one. For sane inputs, that's actually probably simpler. (In this case, I guess I could have used `info complete` as the syntax looks compatible, except then I'd need to build an accumulator and manage that.)

Comment: Thanks..  when i run this script, how can I parse input file?
and how can i read input file in this script and at the end get an output file or override input file?

Comment: Feed the script in as standard input via redirection, and the output comes on standard output. Standard command line stuff. `tclsh myScript.tcl <yourInput.file >yourNew.file`

Comment: : One upgrade in the script: If "Sb(" is already there for some MainContent then script should ignore it.